# Composite, Buttons and Icons

Tags: java, composite

My program is supposed to create circle icons in dialogue.
I have three buttons, each represent a color of the icon to be made.
So, if I click 10 times on various buttons, my program should create 10 circles in various colors.
This is my code, in 2 classes:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CompositeIcon extends JFrame {
        static CircleIcon icon;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
            JButton redBut = new JButton("Red");
            JButton blueBut = new JButton("Blue");
            JButton greenBut = new JButton("Green");

            icon = new CircleIcon();

            redBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        icon.addIcon(new CircleIcon(50, Color.red));
        label.setIcon(icon);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.pack();
        }
    });

            blueBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        icon.addIcon(new CircleIcon(50, Color.blue));
        label.setIcon(icon);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.pack();
        }
    });

            greenBut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        icon.addIcon(new CircleIcon(50, Color.green));
        label.setIcon(icon);
        frame.repaint();
        frame.pack();
        }
    });


        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        frame.add(redBut);
        frame.add(blueBut);
        frame.add(greenBut);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And my other class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CircleIcon implements Icon {
        private ArrayList<Icon> icons;
        private int width;
        private int height;

    public CircleIcon() {
        icons = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    }

    public void addIcon(Icon icon) {
        icons.add(icon);
        width += icon.getIconWidth();
        int iconHeight = icon.getIconHeight();
        if (height < iconHeight)
            height = iconHeight;
    }

    public int getIconHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getIconWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        for (Icon icon : icons) {
            icon.paintIcon(c, g, x, y);
            x += icon.getIconWidth();
        }
    }
}
```

At this point my program won't even compile, and the problem is in the CompositeIcon-class,
at `icon.addIcon(new CircleIcon(50, Color.red));` for the "red-button", and the same for blue and green.

Comment: If i try to run, and press one of my buttons i get the error code:
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor CircleIcon(int, Color) is undefined

 at CompositeIcon$1.actionPerformed(CompositeIcon.java:20)

Comment: @user1054685 why create an Array of Icons

Comment: You shouldn't try to run the code until all compilation errors are fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code. Your CircleIcon class has a constructor missing. Add this to your circle icon class.

```
 public CircleIcon(int number, Color awtColor) {
        // do whatever here
    }
```